# Different behavior when having multiple clip modifiers in jetpack compose in different SDK versions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

I have the following code in jetpack compose in an android project.

```
Button(
    onClick = {  }, 
    modifier = Modifier
         .height(52.dp)
         .clip(RoundedCornerShape(26.dp))
         .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
) {
    Text(text = "This is button.")
  }
```

But I see different results in SDK version 24 and SDK version 32. I expect to have 26 dp corner size but in SDK version 24, the button corners appear to be 12dp instead of the expected 26dp. However, in SDK version 32, the corners are displayed correctly as 26dp. In SDK version 24, the last clip modifier is overriding the former ones but in SDK 32 the highest corner radius is applied. I'm wondering why I'm seeing these differences and when these kinds of inconsistencies may happen regarding different SDK versions in Jetpack compose.